# looping thru union ranges

Tags: excel, vba

How can I loop this code so `rColored` equals only 1 range at a time.
Right now it will check the sheet and find 4 ranges. I want to apply a sort to each of the ranges.

```
For Each rCell In Range("A5:G" & lastrow)
    If rCell.Interior.Color = vbWhite Then
        If rColored Is Nothing Then
            Set rColored = rCell
        Else
            Set rColored = Union(rColored, rCell)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

My data is laid out so Row 5 is a subheader with Rows 6 - 36 is data that applies to the Row 5 subheader. Row 37 is another subheader with its data on rows 38 - 43 and so forth. The subheaders change depending on the project. The overall goal of mine is to apply a sort on each of the ranges but not the subheader. The subheaders are gray and all the data is white.

[image: Example Data]

Comment: Are B5 etc blank and are they the only blank cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, as SJR suspects, cell B5, B37, and so on, are blank, and no other cells in Column B are blank, try the following...

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim rangeAreas As Areas
Set rangeAreas = Range("B5:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas

Dim rangeArea As Range
For Each rangeArea In rangeAreas
    With rangeArea.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 7)
        .Sort _
            key1:=.Cells(1), _
            Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlNo, _
            MatchCase:=False
    End With
Next rangeArea
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There might be a blank in Column B sometimes, but i don't think i will ever have a blank in Column G. This code works great thanks.